# Changing line-height in a textarea causes a vertical scrollbar in IE9 an IE10

Tags: html, textarea, rows, css

I have a textarea that needs to be able to be sized using the *Rows* attribute. I also want to be able to adjust the *line-height* of the text within the textarea. However, this causes a scrollbar **in IE9 and IE10.** Is there a way around this that doesn't involve javascript?

The problem is illustrated in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JYkAX/6/

Here is the html:

```
<textarea rows="3" class="textbox">No line-height
2
3</textarea>
<div class="separator"></div>
<textarea rows="3" class="textbox2">Lineheight = 20px
2
3</textarea>
```

And here is the css:

```
.textbox
{
    overflow: auto;  
}
.textbox2
{
    overflow: auto;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.separator
{
     display: block;
     height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I take it you don't want to set a height in CSS in addition to the rows height? Setting it to 60px would appear to fix the issue.

Comment: Yes. Both line-height and the rows attribute will be changed dynamically, and I was hoping to avoid adding javascript that would calculate the new height explicitly (which wouldn't be hard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your css is fine but to make this work add Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var textArea = $('textarea'),
      lineHeight = parseFloat(textArea.css('lineHeight'));

  textArea.height(lineHeight * textArea.attr('rows'))

});
```

This will define line-height and its auto height.

**I know you mentioned no JS but jquery was my only solution when I had to deal with something similar to this**

Zeke

Comment: This is what I'm trying to achieve, but was hoping to do so without using javascript.

Comment: If there is I would like to know too!

Answer (score 0):

Create an additional css file for ie and set  line-height to e.g. 13px;

Answer (score 0):

```
use this line-height: 15px\9; in css
```

It is a css IE9 hack for modern browsers. it will work. i check it on IE9. You check it on IE10. As i do not have IE10.

Its a good question. I iike it as replied correctly :)

Comment: Hassaan, this will appear to work, since it effectively removes the line-height I'm setting. I still need the line-height...

Comment: thank you dear for reply. it is a new thing thing for me too. i have tried my best for your question.